# Wordpress is picking up links that don't exist

Tags: pages

users online plugin and every time i go to check, i always see that most users are on a page that says "page not found"

and this is the url that i am getting from it

http://www.celebloid.com/wp-content/plugins/lightbox-gallery/js/jquery.lightbox.js

the problem is that directory "lightbox-gallery" doesn't exist.

How do i solve this prblem

Answer (score 0):

Your site has many issues, firstly your jquery is not loading correctly. If I look at what your server is giving me I expected to find a minimised copy of jquery, instead I got a html meta refresh tag.

Because of this, I then get around 10 errors caused by a missing jquery library.

Then, if you look in the  tags of your site, you'll find the references to jquery.lightbox.js, the nonexistant file you are seeing.

I suggest disabling the lightbox-gallery plugin, and opting for an alternative. I would also cut down on the number fo scripts and stylesheets either by merging them or removing them.